# Swift Xcode 11 breakpoints for conditionals do not work

Tags: swift, xcode, breakpoints

I am trying to add a Symbolic Breakpoint in XCode to check for UI engine modifications on the background thread.

What I am doing is the following:

[image]

However, the error message I am getting back is always:

```
Stopped due to an error evaluating condition of breakpoint 5.1: "!Thread.isMainThread"
Couldn't parse conditional expression:
error: use of undeclared identifier 'Thread'

UI Engine must be modified on main thread.
```

I do not understand why the breakpoint condition cannot evaluate my condition.  Can someone explain what I may be doing wrong here? I have tried putting that in Obj-c as well, to no luck.

EDIT: Obj-C version, here: `!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]`

EDIT 2: Xcode version Version 11.3 (11C29)

EDIT 3: Ok, so, closing XCode and reopening has gotten the Obj-C version "working" they pause on a breakpoint for something like, 4-5 minutes each time.  This effectively makes these breakpoints unusable.  Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Can we see your ObjC version of the condition please?

Comment: @matt added an edit

Comment: I was able to get it working by writing it as `(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread] == NO`.

Comment: @matt technically, your answer solved my original issue, so if you want to make it an actual answer I can select it, resulting in the current EDIT 3 that I will be looking further into and if i cannot solve, will make a new stackoverflow post about

Comment: Yeah, I've heard about the "pause on a breakpoint for a long time" problem — it has been asked about before on SO — but I've never seen it myself and have not worked on solving it. I think it's legitimately a different issue (though of course I could be wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get your original symbolic breakpoint working as expected by writing the condition as

```
(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread] == NO
```

I suspect there's a better way, and comparing a BOOL directly to NO is very bad style, but at least it got me past the "doesn't work" stage to the "does work" stage.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, setting symbolic breakpoints and using conditions DOES work, but 
I would hazard that self and Thread are not available as symbols for much of the UIKit framework because there is no debugging information available for most of it, hence the error: use of undeclared identifier 'Thread'.

See the answer in this post:

[How to log out self when add a symbol breakpoint at -[UIViewController viewWillAppear] method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235271/how-to-log-out-self-when-add-a-symbol-breakpoint-at-uiviewcontroller-viewwilla)

There is also additional info about creating symbolic breakpoints for child classes and a possible workaround using an objective-c condition here:

[Using of symbolic breakpoints for child classes in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403719/using-of-symbolic-breakpoints-for-child-classes-in-xcode)

That being said, if you are only interested in particular classes in your modules where that method (layoutSubviews) is invoked, you can specify the module inside your symbolic breakpoint, and if you have your own implementation of that method (e.g. you have overridden it in your class code), the condition Thread.isMainThread or !Thread.isMainThread will in fact work for that class.

I know this may not in fact solve your dilemma, especially if you need to check all the invocations of layoutSubviews, but I hope it at least helps to explain why a condition using Thread does not work all the time.